# Regex to capture tags and contents

Tags: php, regex

I need a php regex solution to capture certain tags and their contents.

I found this one:

`~<tag>(.*?)</tag>~isg`

Which gets everything inside `<tag>`, but I also need it to capture the `<tag>` and `</tag>`

I'm really bad at regex, just can't get my head around it, been stuck on regex101.com to try find a solution for the past hour, but no luck Lol

The solution I need, is if the search text is:

`<tag>Hey1</tag> Blah Blah <tag>Hey2</tag>`

I need to capture:

`<tag>Hey1</tag>`

`<tag>Hey2</tag>`

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? Why not a parser? (There's no `g` modifier in PHP). Take a look at, http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: Regex is much smaller code. With the parser, I have to load the DOMDocument class, and add in the search, tell it what I want etc, it just gets messy ...

Comment: Yeah I know there's no `g` modifier, I just added it so I didn't have to explain I was using the `preg_match_all` ...

Comment: If you move the capture groups it should grab everything. `(<tag>.*?</tag>)`

Comment: I've tried every way I could think of :/ ... Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = '<tag>Hey1</tag> Blah Blah <tag>Hey2</tag>';

preg_match_all('#(<tag>.*?</tag>)#is', $text, $matches);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($matches[1], true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex and parser answers...

Parser:

```
$html = '<tag>Hey1</tag> Blah Blah <tag>Hey2</tag>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$tag = 'tag';
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tag);
foreach ($tags as $foundtag) {
        echo "<$tag>" . $foundtag->nodeValue . "</$tag>";
}
```

Parser output:

```
<tag>Hey1</tag><tag>Hey2</tag>
```

Regex:

```
preg_match_all('~(<tag>.*?</tag>)~is', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Regex Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tag>Hey1</tag>
    [1] => <tag>Hey2</tag>
)
```

Moving the `()` tells the regex what you want to capture. That is a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Comment: Lol, told you the regex way is much simpler :P ... +1 for the full parser code though

Comment: Simpler now. Refer to this when you run into issues with the regex. For example if your `tag` gets attributes..

Comment: I just tell my Regex the same thing that ET would ... 'Beeeeeee... gooood.'

Comment: Haha, sounds like you've got it covered. Good luck.

Comment: Fortunately I don't have to worry about the attributes ... The reason I wanted this, was because I have made an admin page for my website, so that I can update the page content. But some of the content needs to have `htmlspecialchars()` applied .... So I can now just use the tag `<c><\c>` tags to make sure php will escape everything inside, and also remove the tags :D ... Currently I have about 30 lines if recursive `strpos` to do the job Lol